# HTML5 contenteditable div: show placeholder only if div has 1 child

Tags: css, html

I trying to setup placeholder for contenteditable div, but here's problem: placeholder appears and offsets real text even when div loses focus even if it's not empty.

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true" placeholder="Enter the text">
    <br>
</div>
```

... i have to always leave `<br>` there to kill huge cursor (those in the topic). I haven't use `display: block` here.

CSS:

```
[contenteditable=true]:nth-child(1):only-child:not(:focus):before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    color: darkgrey;
}
```

... since the `div`'s empty state is having one child, i tried to tell this to css, but it hasn't effect.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3wM36/. Type something in div and take away focus.

How to fix this?

Comment: The `placeholder` attribute is not allowed for a `div` element. If you wish to set up your own placeholder thing, use a `data-*` attribute for it.

Comment: The jsfiddle does not work. The question does not really explain what the goal and the idea is, why the `br` tag is used, and what really happens.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, JSFiddle is updated. `br` tag used to prevent hude cursor on whole height of div, which you will see in empty `inline-block` div

Comment: Your CSS refers to a `div` that is the only child of its parent, not to its children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot select an element with CSS selectors on the basis of its children. Neither is such selection needed, if you wish to simulate the effect of a `placeholder` attribute for an editable `div` element. The way `placeholder` works is that it is shown when there is no user input in the field, and *this* has a counterpart: you can test whether an element is empty (i.e. has no content – no child elements and no plain text either). Example:

```
<style>
[contenteditable=true] {
    border: solid 1px; /* Just to show what the area is. */
    min-height: 1.2em;
}
[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    color: darkgrey;
}
</style>
<div contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Enter the text"></div>
```

Comment: You are right, but it will work only for empty div. But if you will add `display: inline-block` (i have to use only `inline-block`) to your div, you will get "huge cursor" effect. And the only way to fix this is add extra `<br>` tag to the empty div before it's usage. Such hack. That's why i mentioned `<br>` in my question. So i need to echo placeholder only if div contains only one child, because the div will never become empty.

Comment: You did not mention `inline-block` in the question, and I don’t see any huge cursor if I test your jsfiddle with the `<br>` tag removed. And as I commented, you cannot select an element in CSS by its children. I think you should present (probably as a new question) your *original* problem that made you think you need to declare the element as inline block (and, if you really need to do that, show a sample code that actually produces the “huge cursor” effect).

Comment: yeah it's my fail. The style of div also contains inner padding, which i forgot to mention, that drops cursor down like it endless. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

Just remove your placeholder attribute

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <br>
</div>
```

css:

```
    div {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        border: 1px solid gainsboro;
        position:relative;
    }
    div[contenteditable=true]:nth-child(1):only-child:not(:focus):before{
        content:'Enter the text';
        color: darkgrey;
        position:absolute;
    }
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3wM36)

Comment: Better a lot, but it still overlaps first line. Are there ways to get round this?